# Request external api when developing Outlook add-in

Tags: outlook, office-js, office-addins

We are developing additional Outlook features.

I am getting an error when trying to post request to an external api.

I have registered the app domain in the manifest file, why can't I access the external api?

(I use angularjs and the backend uses asp.net core.)

Also, the part requested by the api cannot be confirmed on the network.

Comment: Are you able to make a successful POST request outside of the Outlook add-in? For example, does POST request succeed in Fiddler? Which Outlook client(s) does this issue repro in?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure CORS is supported on both sides. Or JSONP is used.

The same-origin policy enforced by the browser prevents a script loaded from one domain from getting or manipulating properties of a webpage from another domain. This means that, by default, the domain of a requested URL must be the same as the domain of the current webpage. For example, this policy will prevent a webpage in one domain from making XmlHttpRequest web-service calls to a domain other than the one where it is hosted.

Because Office Add-ins are hosted in a browser control, the same-origin policy applies to script running in their web pages as well.

The same-origin policy can be an unnecessary handicap in many situations, such as when a web application hosts content and APIs across multiple subdomains. There are a few common techniques for securely overcoming same-origin policy enforcement.

1. One way to overcome same-origin policy limitations is to use [JSONP](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_jsonp.asp) to provide a proxy for the web service. You do this by including a script tag with a src attribute that points to some script hosted on any domain. You can programmatically create the script tags, dynamically create the URL to point the src attribute to, and then pass parameters to the URL via URI query parameters. Web service providers create and host JavaScript code at specific URLs, and return different scripts depending on the URI query parameters. These scripts then execute where they are inserted and work as expected.
2. Another way to address same-origin policy limitations is to provide server-side code that uses OAuth 2.0 flows to enable one domain to get authorized access to resources hosted on another.
3. Use the cross-origin resource sharing feature of [XmlHttpRequest2](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/xhr/raw-file/tip/Overview.html), see the "Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)" section of [New Tricks in XMLHttpRequest2](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/).

Finally, I'd suggest using Fiddler to understand what is going on under the hood of HTTP (ajax) calls.

Comment: I set cors in startup.cs When I make a request to a controller using the same domain, it stops responding.
this._http.post("https://localhost:xxxx/api/", param)
      This is a request using .subscribe(res => {})